# How to transform element progressively based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to use waypoints for two specific functions.

1. To determine is the user is scrolling up or down. This is working.
2. The second thing I am trying to figure out how to do doesn't necessarily have to do with waypoints. What I am trying to figure out is how to get the image in the snippet to progressively transform: translateX based on the scroll progression. I am not sure how to do this. I put translate in the snippet to show the movement.

Basically if your scroll down, I am wanting the image to move to the left progressively based on how far down scrolled in comparison to the section/container it is held. The same applies when scrolling up, except the image moving to the right.

[Check out this site](https://fishermenlabs.com/) and scroll down a little to the "Nike and Snapchat" section, you will see a phone image of Lebron. As you progressively scroll up or down, the image moves accordingly. This is what I am trying to replicate.

Does anyone know what I can do to achieve this?

```js
var homeMainSec =  $('#homeMainSec');
 
homeMainSec.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('#homeBoxGridRight img').addClass('slideLeftDisplay');
    console.log('Left Slide');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
homeMainSec.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $('#homeBoxGridRight img').addClass('slideRightDisplay');
    console.log('Right Slide');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
```

```css
#homeMainSec {
 width: 100%;
 height: 95vh;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 70px;
}
.homeMainBlock {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*- HomeBoxGridRight Section -*/
#homeBoxGridRight img {
 display: block;
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 50%;
}
.slideLeftDisplay {
 transform: translateX(-100px);-webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
}
.slideRightDisplay {
 transform: translateX(100px);-webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<section id="homeMainSec">
  <div class="homeMainBlock" id="homeBoxGridLeft">
  </div><div class="homeMainBlock" id="homeBoxGridRight">
    <img src="https://slidesjs.com/examples/standard/img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Image">
  </div>
</section>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

ge of Lebron. As you progressively scroll up or down, the image moves accordingly. This is what I am trying to replicate.

Does anyone know what I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
  document.querySelector('img').style.transform = 'translateX(' + scroll_pos + '%)';
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried integrating this with my snippet above and I can't quite figure out the progression part and the % part. No matter what % I put in the image slides off the page. https://jsfiddle.net/g02dvshu/

Comment: Works for me with: `document.querySelector('img').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + scroll_pos + '%)';` (Notice the minus in front of scroll_pos)

Comment: Awesome. Is there anyway to limit how far over to the left the img goes? Ideally, I would only like it to go over as far as `left: 50%;`.

Comment: You can use an if-statement:
`if (scroll_pos > 50) { // change image translate`
Or you can multiply by a value to change the speed of the "animation": `.transform = 'translateX(' + (scroll_pos * .5) + '%)';` (.5 to make it go half as fast)

Comment: Thanks the slower speed definitely helps. Could you give an examples of the if (scroll_pos > 50)? I'm not sure how I would set the stop and not make it jump.